# PhpPowerpoint class XMLwriter not found

Tags: php, xmlwriter, phppowerpoint

I'm trying to use PHPPowerpoint and his examples

But I get the following error :

```
*Sample 01 Complex
14:56:03 Create new PHPPresentation object
14:56:03 Set properties
14:56:03 Remove first slide
14:56:03 Create templated slide
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create templated slide
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create templated slide
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create templated slide
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)
14:56:03 Create a shape (rich text)

**Fatal error: Class 'Common\XMLWriter' not found in .....\test phppowerpoint\PHPPowerPoint-develop\src\PhpPresentation\Writer\PowerPoint2007\AbstractPart.php on line 76***
```

Can anyone help me to fix this error ?
Thank you

Comment: I have the same issue, I am not able to understand the directory structure and where to place the common-develop folder?

Answer (score 4):

You are facing this problem because `common office php` files are missing. Download:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/Common

and include it in your source code (after updating the path):

```
require_once 'Common-develop/src/Common/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();
```

Comment: Can you explain where actually I do have to place these common files in directory? As, there is no folder like PhpOffice

Comment: Can you please tell me where do i need to store these Common library files?

Answer (score 1):

As Raj said, you need to download the common PHPOffice classes from the link he specified.
You can place them where is more convenient to you. In my case, I placed the *Common* folder inside the *src* folder (so in *src* you'd have *PHPPresentation* and *Common*). 
Afterwards, you need to include them in the source code, as Raj said

```
require_once 'PHPPresentation/src/Common/Autoloader.php;
\PhpOffice\Common\Autoloader::register();
```

You'll have to update the path in *require_once* to your actual path.

P.S.: Don't forget about writing permissions on the destination folder, otherwise the library won't be able to write out the presentation file!